# Sample size re-estimation in an adaptive seamless phase II/III trial with interim analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size, sample, statistical-power, clinical-trials

I have an adaptive clinical trial that includes these elements:

Seamless phase II/III: phase III follows immediately after phase II ends. Phase II has a different endpoint than phase III's endpoints.

Phase II: Randomizing assigning patients to receive placebo or treatment. It's double-blinded.

"Cross-over": Not a true cross-over, the "cross-over" refers to placebo crossing into receiving treatment (Tx)

Open label extension (Phase III): The same treatment was given to all patients (regardless if they are previously from placebo or treatment group). And the treatment is unblinded.

Interim analysis: After phase II is done, an interim analysis will be conducted before the beginning of phase III in order to do sample size re-estimation to ensure it has enough power (80%).

It is depicted as such:

[image]

How can sample size be calculated to ensure the study to have at least 80% power?

Comment: You cannot use data from a randomized double blinded placebo controlled trial to calculate the sample size in an open label phase III extension. Generally, open label studies have a healthier placebo cohort because sicker subjects prefer the active treatment and so will either select it more often, or drop out of the study if it's their randomly assigned treatment.